# Building XML stream messages with Smack on Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, xmpp, smack, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to authenticate my connection with Firebase-Cloud-Messaging via the Smack Library. I see that my connection gets a streamId from google because I log this message on my Android Studio IDE: 
    Log.d("MyStreamId", "Ddd: "+ connection.getStreamId());
My logs return a random alpha-numeric number so it means Google's CCS is noticing my connection attempt. Now, according to this link: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#connecting
There must be some type of communication exchange, in order to authenticate my connection,between my "app server" and Google's CCS. I am trying to start this communication which uses XML formatting.

I need to construct the following "xml stream" and send it with my connection using the Smack Library:

```
<stream:stream to="gcm.googleapis.com"
    version="1.0" xmlns="jabber:client"
    xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams">
```

What I am trying to do is creating a HashMap with the keys: "to", "version", "xmlns". Am I missing another key in this HashMap?

Also, how should I proceed afterwards? Should I turn this HashMap to some Json object? I've worked with JSON before on Android Studio. Should I use the method from Smack Library toXML() to convert the HashMap to a stream? Notice the  tags on the XML object. Also, how would I send it to Google's CCS using my connection object which is an XMPPAbstractConnection object? My connection object also has an addAsyncStanzaListener object in the hopes of receiving bi-directional communication from Google's CCS.

Any thoughts or ideas will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You asked a few questions here, but I think you may be misunderstanding the intended design of using XMPP with FCM. I will try to correct that, and you can refine your question.

In general you should not be using XMPP on your Android client. The idea is to use XMPP client on your application server to connect to and communicate with CCS. Android will maintain a best-effort connection between the device and FCM, note that this cannot be an constantly open connection like it can be on your server since that would kill the device's battery.

Comment: from the following example at this link:  http://www.grokkingandroid.com/xmpp-server-google-cloud-messaging/

Comment: from the following link:  http://www.grokkingandroid.com/xmpp-server-google-cloud-messaging/                          I see that Smack is used as an interface to communicate with Firebase CCS. Based on this, Smack API's act as communication means with Firebase CCS. Now, in the friendlyping application on Github they use a Go Server to communicate with GCM. In this other link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#connecting  towards the middle. There's an exchange of "xml" between CCS and App Server.Where does it take place? in the app code or external. @arthurthompson

Comment: CCS (part of FCM) is an XMPP server. It allows your app server to act as an XMPP client (using Smack for eg) with an open connection to CCS. Messages are JSON wrapped in XML eg: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#xmpp_message

Comment: I got the connection set up.. I avoided all the authentication exchange between my app server and CCS. I guess Smack took care of this in the background with its methods. However, the connection is not secured but at least is connected. I need to implement building the stanzas to send upstream, ack, nack and downstream messaging. I've seen several good examples on this.. So It shouldn't be difficult to implement. This communication interface will reside inside my app. Thanks for any clarification. @ArthurThompson